# We say “documents texte” or “documents textes” ?

Tags: pluriel, appositions

In French, what is the plural of “un document texte”? Is it “des documents texte” or “des documents textes”? I think it is the former, but I am not sure. Additionally, can you explain to me how the “s” works in French for the second word in general ?

Comment: Pour moi c'est des "documents texte", dans la mesure où ce sont **des documents** qui fournissent **du texte**. Pour les règles d'accord des mots composés :  http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/pluriel-noms-composes.php  et http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4429

Comment: I'd only have documents in the plural because I consider they are documents that produce some text (and not texts). Like I'd say "pause café" (pauses during which you drink coffee). You can visit those two websites for rules : http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/pluriel-noms-composes.php and  http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4429

Comment: Question similaire: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11063/tortues-luth-ou-tortues-luths-sur-quelle-r%c3%a8gle-sappuyer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

“Document texte” itself isn't a real composite word, so the answer would be ”Documents texte“, as it's just a shortener for “Documents (de type/having the type) texte”.

Anyway, we can find [a sheet here](http://www.journaldunet.com/management/efficacite-personnelle/orthographe-les-pieges-a-eviter/des-pluriels-trompeurs.shtml) about plurals of composite words, and this specific example should fall in the “Nom(s) + nom complément” category.

Answer (score 5):

Si j'interprète correctement l'[avis de l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#13_strong-em-apposition-les-danseuses-toiles-regardent-des-films-culte-em-strong) à ce sujet :

> Au pluriel, dans des syntagmes comme *danseuse étoile*, *film culte*, *produit phare* ou *mot clé*, qui sont formés d’un nom mis en apposition à un autre nom, le mot apposé suit la règle suivante : il varie uniquement si on peut établir une relation d’équivalence entre celui-ci et le mot auquel il est apposé.
>
> Ainsi, on écrira *Les danseuses étoiles regardent des films culte*, car si l’on considère que les danseuses sont des étoiles (elles ont les mêmes propriétés qu’elles, elles brillent de la même façon), il est évident que les films ne sont pas des cultes, mais qu’ils font l’objet d’un culte.

Les documents sont bien des textes et on écrirait par conséquent *des documents textes*. Cela ne me parait pas bien différent des *danseuses étoiles*.

---

In short, we write *des documents textes* because in this apposition document and text refer to the same entity. In the case of *films culte*, the situation is different because these movies are obviously not cults; they are the objects of those cults.