# «Tortues luth» ou «Tortues luths»? Sur quelle règle s'appuyer?

Tags: pluriel, appositions

Dans la phrase suivante :

> Toutes les **tortues luth** femelles pondent leurs œufs à leur lieu de naissance.

Devrait-on accorder «luth» au pluriel? S'il s'agissait d'un adjectif qualificatif, ce serait évident, mais ici l'usage inhabituel de «luth», qui est un substantif, mais fait hésiter. Sur quelle règle s'appuyer?

Comment: Question similaire: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/we-say-documents-texte-or-documents-textes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cet article](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4661) de l'Office québécois de la langue française appelle *nom épithète* cet usage d'un nom à la manière d’un adjectif, et donne quelques conseils pour savoir s'il faut faire l'accord de nombre.

En premier lieu il faut distinguer s'il s'agit d'un *nom en apport de qualification* ou d'un *nom en apport de complémentation*. Comme on peut dire *tortue qui est comme un luth*, il s'agit d'un nom en apport de qualification. À propos de ce type de nom épithète, l'article dit:

> Le nom en apport de qualification a tendance à varier en nombre quand le nom qu’il caractérise est pluriel, mais l’usage n’est, dans bien des cas, pas encore fixé. De fait, certains ouvrages de langue se limitent à recenser les noms en apport de qualification qui varient d’ordinaire en nombre et ceux pour lesquels l’usage est flottant. Par exemple : *des congrès monstres*, mais *des serviettes éponge* ou *éponges*. Plusieurs dictionnaires de difficultés, par contre, suggèrent l’accord généralisé du nom en apport de qualification. La BDL aussi. Il est vrai qu’habituellement, le nom ne reçoit pas les marques de genre ou de nombre d’autres mots dans la phrase. Ainsi, certains scripteurs choisissent parfois, dans les cas non consacrés par l’usage, de ne pas faire varier le nom en apport de qualification. Cela ne saurait être considéré comme fautif, mais il nous apparaît tout de même plus cohérent de proposer l’accord. Pourquoi? Parce que le nom en apport de qualification joue un rôle syntaxique très semblable à celui de l’adjectif. La proposition vise à simplifier le raisonnement grammatical et, somme toute, elle s’inscrit dans la tendance générale.

Donc, les auteurs préfèrent l'accord de nombre, mais il n'y a pas de règle définitive dans ce cas et il faut tourner à l'usage, qui ne donne pas non plus un résultat concluant:

- Google Ngrams place les occurences de "tortues luths" [à peu près à égalité](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tortues+luths%2Ctortues+luth&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctortues%20luths%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctortues%20luth%3B%2Cc0) avec "tortues luth".
- [L'article Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tortue_luth) utilise toujours le singulier, mais dans la bibliographie on trouve quelques articles publiés dans revues spécialisées qui utilisent le pluriel et quelques autres qui utilisent le singulier.
- [L'article de l'encyclopédie Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/vie-sauvage/tortue_luth/184824) cité par Xavier utilise presque toujours le pluriel mais dans un cas le singulier est utilisé. Ce dernier peut être simplement un erreur typographique.

Comment: Entretemps, un autre [article de l'OQLF sur les mots composés](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4429) m'avait mis la puce à l'oreille, mais voilà qui est beaucoup plus directement lié au problème. Merci!

Comment: Argument supplémentaire: un grand nombres de combinaisons (par ex, *serviette éponge*) sont pratiquement, d'un point de vue plus abstrait, des noms composés, et s'ils avaient un trait d'union, entreraient dans la catégorie où les deux mots s'accordent.

Answer (score 1):

Dans l'encyclopédie Larrouse, on trouve:

> Des concentrations de plusieurs dizaines de **tortues luths** ont pu être été observées ; elles étaient sans doute en train de se nourrir sur des bancs de méduses.

Il semblerait donc qu'il faille mettre un **s** a luth. Dans **chats-tigres** c'est différent car il y a un tiret entre **chat** et **tigre**.

Est-ce que quelqu'un peut expliquer la règle?

Comment: Ici: http://french.stackexchange.com/a/9610/79

Comment: Merci pour le lien :-)