# Le mot « objet » s'accorde-t-il au pluriel dans cette phrase ?

Tags: pluriel

Est-ce qu'on dit

> les matériaux objets du marché ...

Ou bien

> les matériaux objet du marché ...

S'il vous plait pourquoi ? J'ai cherché dans le Wiktionnaire mais en vain.

Comment: Quel est le contexte ? Est-ce que "matériaux objet(s)" est un terme (comme on dirait "porte manteau") ? Il serait plus simple de comprendre l'accord en essayant de reformuler la phrase, et en écrivant la suite pour connaitre les différents groupements... (verbe singulier, pluriel... ?)

Comment: Cf. https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11063/, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/, … Dans ce cas « objets », mais je reformulerais.

Answer (score 4):

Si je devais l'écrire sous une autre forme, j'écrirais:

> les matériaux concernés par le marché

Avec « concernés » au pluriel. J'écrirais donc « objets » au pluriel également…

*Suite au commentaire de Toto :* À noter qu'il s'agit selon moi d'un dilemme classique. Doit-on écrire « Le kilo de pommes que j'ai mangées » (J'ai mangé les pommes) ou « Le kilo de pommes que j'ai mangé » (j'ai mangé le kilo de pommes) ? Si je ne me trompe, les 2 formules sont grammaticalement correctes. Le choix de l'une ou l'autre dépend selon moi du bon sens, de l'intention : comme au final on mange les pommes, chaque élément du collectif « kilo » on préfèrera je pense la formule au pluriel.

Dans un cas comme « Le groupe de personne que j'ai accompagné », je pense que l'intention donne l'accord: un guide touristique accompagne par exemple à priori plutôt le groupe (collectif) que chaque individu, on préfèrera donc le singulier. Si c'est chaque individu qui est concerné par l'action, on préfèrera sans doute le pluriel.

En cherchant, je suis tombé sur [cet article](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/accord-avec-un-sujet-singulier-ayant-un-sens-pluriel-a5352133) qui me semble assez complet sur le sujet.

Comment: Mais pourquoi pas: « Les matériaux qui sont l'objet du marché » ?

Comment: Bonne remarque, Je pense simplement que "les matériaux" n'est pas une manière de les regrouper, il me semble dès lors incongru d'utiliser un singulier. Si l'on avait écrit "Le lot de matériaux", je pense alors que le singulier aurait été plus approprié. J'ai néanmoins étoffé ma réponse suite à ta remarque.

Comment: Effectivement. Je te donne mon vote pour ta réponse complétée.

Comment: je pense qu'avec les parenthèses, on peut mieux expliquer l'exemple du groupe de personnes : "(Le groupe de personnes) que j'ai accompagné", ou "Le groupe de (personnes que j'ai accompagnées)". Mais je pense que la structure grammaticale s'éloigne de celle de la question...

Comment: Le lien est en effet très intéressant

Comment: Il n'est pas question de nom collectif dans cet exemple. Le lien n'explique pas ce cas-là.

Answer (score 0):

Pour qui a un peu pratiqué la rédaction de contrats commerciaux – c'est mon cas –, la réponse ne fait pas de doute : il s'agit bien de marchandises "objet du marché".
Elles sont en général visées collectivement dans un paragraphe qui s'appelle "Objet" (ou équivalent). Le nombre d'articles ne joue aucun rôle dans l'accord.